# Add and order row on SQL result

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a way to always get a define number of row in my SQL result (Oracle).
Let me show you what i meen.
Here's an extract of my table

```
|----------|----------|----------|
|   DATE   |  NUMBER  |   TYPE   |
|----------|----------|----------|
| 12/01/13 |    2     |    A     |
| 12/01/13 |    4     |    B     |
| 12/02/13 |    3     |    D     |
| 12/02/13 |    1     |    A     |
| 12/02/13 |    5     |    X     |
|----------|----------|----------|
```

I need to always get 5 rows in my result for a chosen date, so complete it with new rows and "null" value.
Here's what i hope the result will look like for 12/01/13

```
|----------|----------|----------|
|   DATE   |  NUMBER  |   TYPE   |
|----------|----------|----------|
| 12/01/13 |    1     |   null   |
| 12/01/13 |    2     |    A     |
| 12/01/13 |    3     |   null   |
| 12/01/13 |    4     |    B     |
| 12/01/13 |    5     |   null   |
|----------|----------|----------|
```

The idea is the same for the other date. i kind a did something with a lot of UNION but it wasn't working very well.

So how would you write this SELECT query ?

Thanks

Comment: You gotta take the first crack at this SQL.  If you get stuck, let us know.

Comment: There is fairly new and specialised syntax in Oracle for data densification, and nobody seems to have heard of it, so I went ahead and posted a partition outer join example. There's a load of other ways of doing it that would also be valid in other RDBMSs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partition outer join will fill in the gaps.

```
with cte_number_list as (
  select     rownum my_number
  from       dual
  connect by level <= 5)
select t.my_date,
       l.my_number,
       t.type
from   cte_number_list l left outer join
       my_table        t partition by (t.my_date)
                         on l.my_number = t.my_number;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG02013

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, something like this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE #Numbers ( Number INT );
INSERT #Numbers (Number) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

SELECT Dates.Date, #Numbers.Number, Type
FROM #Numbers, (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM MyTable) AS Dates
LEFT JOIN MyTable ON MyTable.Date = Dates AND MyTable.Number = #Numbers.Number
```

Edit: This example probably won't work with Oracle. I just realised that the question was regarding Oracle SQL after I wrote it. Leaving the answer here anyway. If someone knows how to translate it into Oracle SQL syntax, please feel free to edit my answer.